# How can I run a quartz schedule on mondays and tuesdays every two weeks?

Tags: c#, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, cronexpression

I used the below way to run the schedule on every two weeks on mondays.

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                    .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(StartHour, StartMinute, StartSeconds, StartDate, StartMonth, StartYear))
                                    .WithCalendarIntervalSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInWeeks(Int32.Parse(nWeekInterval)))
                                    .EndAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(0, 0, 0, EndDay, EndMonth, EndYear))
                                    .Build();
```

But how can  I use a single schedule to run on mondays and tuesdays as well. Please advice.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify days of the week with `DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder`

```
var onMondayAndTuesday = DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder.Create()
                         .OnDaysOfTheWeek(new DayOfWeek[] { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday });

var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                            .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(StartHour, StartMinute, StartSeconds, StartDate, StartMonth, StartYear))
                            .WithSchedule(onMondayAndTuesday)
                            .WithCalendarIntervalSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInWeeks(Int32.Parse(nWeekInterval)))
                            .EndAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(0, 0, 0, EndDay, EndMonth, EndYear))
                            .WithIdentity(triggerKey)
                            .Build();
```

Comment: This is invalid code. You can't specify two different kinds of schedule (daily and calendar here).

Answer (score 1):

I would create one job with two different triggers. Each trigger fires biweekly (or semi-monthly).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following expression to schedule a job to run on alternate Mondays and tuesdays.

```
0 0 0 1-7,15-21,29-31 * 1,2 *
```

Here is how the expression is described.

0 -- 0th sec

0 -- 0th min

0 -- 0th hr

1-7,15-21,29-31 -- on alternate week of the month

- -- any month

1,2 -- On Monday and Tuesday

- -- Any year.

Comment: Cronmaker.com says this expression is invalid. Please help

Comment: Shetty87 Could you post a full example of a quartz cron job ?