# Is it possible to create Outlook like schedules with Quartz scheduler?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I would like to be able to create this kind of schedule:

Thursday and Friday 3PM every N weeks.

If there was no requirement for "every N weeks" I could use CronScheduler.

Only way I can think of is to split this into two weekly schedules with interval in 7 days x N weeks. But this is problematic. How to make it easy for client to modify such schedule? Two internal schedules is implementation detail he shouldn't worry about.

This is how it looks in Outlook.
[image]

Is it possible to implement this as one schedule? Maybe I should/have to create my custom trigger for this? I need to support all schedules that Outlook supports.

Comment: What is too broad in this question? It is very specific. "Is it possible to implement this as one schedule?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a quartz schedule on mondays and tuesdays every two weeks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337861/how-can-i-run-a-quartz-schedule-on-mondays-and-tuesdays-every-two-weeks)